# Vertical Scrolling not working with some React Component like React-slick and some div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, vertical-scrolling, react-slick

I am unable to scroll through my page while swiping with react-slick or some other react components like a banner or div.

Comment: This question is missing a lot of details.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.